# Is there a "dynamic decltype"?

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, decltype

This question is related to `decltype` and multiple inheritance.

Assume I have the following:

- an abstract class A with a few virtual methods,
- a few derived classes that implement methods using the previous virtual ones (each of these classes is a sort of use-case),
- a final concrete class that inherits from a subset of the previous use-cases and implements the pure virtual methods.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

/**
 * "Iterable container"
 */
template <class T>
struct A
{
    virtual T* data() =0;
    virtual const T* data() const =0;
    virtual unsigned size() const =0;

    T* begin() { return data(); }
    T* end() { return data()+size(); }

    const T* begin() const { return data(); }
    const T* end() const { return data()+size(); }
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Iterative assignment
 */
template <class T>
struct B: public A<T>
{
    auto operator =( const T& val ) -> decltype(*this)
    {
        for ( auto& v: *this ) v = val;
        return *this;
    }
};

/**
 * Iterative display
 */
template <class T>
struct C: public A<T>
{
    void show() const
    {
        for ( auto& v: *this )
            std::cout<< v << " ";
            std::cout<< std::endl;
    }
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Concrete implementation
 */
template <class T, unsigned N>
struct D:
    public B<T>, 
    public C<T>
{
    using B<T>::operator=;

    T dat[N];

    T* data() { return dat; }
    const T* data() const { return dat; }
    unsigned size() const { return N; }
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    D<double,5> d;
    (d = 42).show(); // compile-time error, "no member named 'show' in 'B<double>'"
}
```

The problem is this (no pun intended); if one of the "use-case" method should return a reference to `*this`, I would like `this` to be a reference to the final concrete class, so that I could chain the call with other methods from other use-cases.

With the previous implementation however, I'm getting a compile-time error. Is there another way to achieve what I explained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use CRTP; you tell `B` to return an lvalue reference to `D<T, N>` by passing the most derived type as an additional template parameter.

```
template <class T, class Derived>
struct B: public A<T>
{
    auto operator =( const T& val ) -> Derived&
    // ...

template <class T, unsigned N>
struct D:
    public B<T, D<T, N>>,
    // ...
```

Comment: Very interesting! Isn't this going to create a "circular definition" type of problem when we write `D<T,N>` in the inheritance list?

Comment: It doesn't, because return types in member function declarations are allowed to be incomplete class types. By the time you instantiate the member function body the `D<T, N>` is complete so it all works.

Answer (score 3):

You can give `D` an overriding `operator=` that returns a `D &`:

```
auto operator =( const T& val ) -> decltype(*this) override
{
    B<T>::operator=(val);
    return *this;
}
```

This works because `D &` is covariant with `B &`, and overriding functions must have a covariant return type. This currently shadows `B`'s `operator=`, too, because that one is not `virtual`.

Comment: How about `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now :) This is a good solution, but it essentially requires to re-implement every method returning `*this`, which doesn't seem ideal to me.

Comment: @Nawaz, The question is tagged C++11, so I presume that's what's being used.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn, True, though at least you can reuse the base's implementation, and I have to question having so many such functions that it becomes a problem.

Comment: Note that you can mix this implementation with @ecatmur's implementation: have a pure-virtual base, a CRTP helper, and a final implementation.  The CRTP helper extends the pure-virtual methods with correct-typed return values.  This is only useful if you intend to pass around pointers to the pure-virtual base.